# Given that $x,y,z$ are positive reals such that $xyz=32$.What is the minimum value of $x^2+4xy+4y^2+2z^2$.

Tags: calculus, supremum-and-infimum

Given that $x,y,z$ are positive reals such that $xyz=32$.What is the minimum value of $x^2+4xy+4y^2+2z^2$.

---

I could solve this question by Lagrange Multiplier method.And i found the minimum value of the expression as $96$.
I tried other methods to find the minimum value like AM-GM inequality,but i could not solve it.Can someone please tell me a method other than Lagrange Multiplier to find its minimum value.

Comment: This was there in the VMC test yesterday, wasn't it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a matter of arranging terms to get $xyz$ right.  Using AM-GM,
$$x^2+2xy+2xy+4y^2+z^2+z^2\ge 6\sqrt[6]{16x^4y^4z^4}=96$$
As equality is possible when $x=2y=z=4$ we have the minimum.

Comment: How did you know to split the left hand side exactly like that so AM-GM turns out so nice? I automatically tried to factor $x^2+4xy+y^4$ and apply AM-GM from there which didn't get me very far.

Comment: @user2770287 Here I went iteratively, having the expression as is would give $x^3y^3z^2$ under the radical, and from there splitting the $4xy$ and $2z^2$ was the next obvious step.  $ \quad $Of course if one *knew* somehow that $x=z=4, y=2$ gives the minimum, then the obvious way to start is to keep all terms equal in value...

Answer (score 0):

You could substitute $x = \frac{32}{yz}$ and then get $f(y,z) = (\frac{32}{yz})^2+4\cdot 32/z + 4y^2+2z^2$. Then search the minimum of this function.
[link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimum+%2832%2F%28y*z%29%29%5E2%2B4*32%2Fz%2B4*y%5E2%2B2*z%5E2)